# Can I start Outlook 2010 without a splash screen?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

So the new Office 2010 beta is out.  Can I start Outlook 2010 without the fancy splash screen?  Is there some command line argument I can pass?  Some registry flag I can set?

Comment: May I ask why you want to disable the splash screen? If it is because you think disabling it would speed up startup time you might be in for a disappointment...

Comment: I work for http://litmus.com, we do email testing, what happens is the splash screen is a windows form and occasionally our software can mistake it for an email and attempt to take a snapshot of it.  We basically get around this by just waiting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see one documented **anywhere** for Outlook 2007 unfortunately, not even on their [switches page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP012185891033.aspx). Microsoft uses various switches to disable the logo on other products, /q, /nologo, /e, /splash -- none of which seem to work with Outlook. The only registry one I know of for Outlook was for Outlook Express 5, which was NoSplash in the registry as a DWORD. Doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer for now but hopefully this will change when it comes out of beta :-)

Answer (score 1):

Start Outlook with the following `.vbs` script:

```
Set WshShell=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE""",7,FALSE
```

To create the script:

1. Click Start, type 'Notepad' into the search box and press Enter.
2. Copy and paste the above code into Notepad.
3. Click **File**, **Save**
4. Name the file (including quotation marks) `"Start Outlook.vbs"`

Comment: Just tested and this works on office 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SplashKiller](http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/SplashKiller/index.html)

It's working for Office XP and 2003. I hope it works for Office 2007!

> SplashKiller lets you hide those splash screens that appear when an application is loading.
>
> It saves you from having to:
>
> 1. Find a 'no splash screen' option (if one exists) in the application.
> 2. Modify your registry to turn off a splash screen.
> 3. Hack the application itself to remove the splash screen.