# Disable Outlook 2003 splash screen when auto-starting

Tags: boot, microsoft-outlook-2003, splash

I want to hide the splash screen of Outlook 2003. I currently have it set to auto-start and hide to icon.

Every time I start my computer I see the Outlook splash screen which makes me think that it's slowing down the OS to become "operational" after startup.

What do I change in settings to not have the splash screen display on startup?

Comment: You mention 2003, but read these: http://superuser.com/questions/98660/just-looking-to-disable-the-splash-screen-in-microsoft-outlook-2007 http://superuser.com/questions/94922/can-i-start-outlook-2010-without-a-splash-screen

Comment: It **is** slowing down the OS to become operational at start.  Outlook is doing a lot of work in the background while that screen is up.

Comment: As @Joel Coehoorn said, the screen is not the problem, its Outlook. Even if you do hide the screen, your computer will still be slow to start, just this way you it won't be obvious what's slowing it down.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [SplashKiller](http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/SplashKiller/index.html)

It's working for Office XP and 2003.

> SplashKiller lets you hide those splash screens that appear when an application is loading.
>
> It saves you from having to:
>
> 1. Find a 'no splash screen' option (if one exists) in the application.
> 2. Modify your registry to turn off a splash screen.
> 3. Hack the application itself to remove the splash screen.

Comment: This program didn't work on WinVista, so I removed it!

Comment: Ok.. ok... Tell me why you downvote when the word "Vista" is even not listed in that page?!

Comment: You only mentioned "It's working for Office XP and 2003" but did not mention on which versions of Windows this product works on, plus the website doesn't mention which Windows SplashKiller works on.

Comment: FYI: [reshack](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/reshack_setup.exe) works even on Win7 and is a whole lot easier to use than that SplashKiller piece-of-junk!